# Error while using ProtoBuf-Net with flags enum

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

While using ProtoBuf-Net and serializing an enum property, where the enum is set to [FlagsAttribute], I received the following error message when serializing an enum value composed of multiple flags.

The error is: The value (MyEnum.MyValue) has no wire-representation for property MyProperty

Where **MyEnum** is:

```
[Flags]
public Enum MyEnum
{
    MyValue = 0,
    MyValue1 = 1,
    MyValue2 = 2,
    MyValue4 = 4,
    MyValue8 = 8,
}
```

and

```
MyProperty = MyEnum.MyValue2 | MyEnum.MyValue4;
```

Seems to be a bug in protobuf-net?

Comment: Now fixed in r274; see updated answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update : this is now fixed in [r274](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/downloads/list); you would use:

```
[ProtoMember(12, DataFormat = DataFormat.TwosComplement)]
public MyEnum MyValue {get;set;}
```

---

Ultimately the protocol buffers wire 
format doesn't provide any scope for [Flags] enums - it enforces enum values against 
the discreet set. I could allow this easily enugh, but:

- I'd probably have to disable enum mappings in this case, or do a lot of ugly bit-
  matching work
- it would not be strictly compatible

An easier way of doing this may be to do a shim in your code:

```
public MyEnum MyValue {get;set;}
[ProtoMember(12)]
private int MyValueWire {
    get {return (int)MyValue;}
    set {MyValue = (MyEnum)value;}
}
```

The other alternative would be to add a flag that works like the above on your 
behalf; treating it as an int rather than an enum.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply. I would prefer the last alternative where I would put a flag to the ProtoMember attribute to indicate that the enum should be treated as an int.

Comment: It would be nice to set the `DataFormat` in the enum ProtoContract class itself.

Comment: @Gerard note that `[Flags]` have bypassed validation for many years, and in v3: all enums are always pass-thru