# OverflowException when serializing a Flags Enum with protobuf-net

Tags: c#, enums, protobuf-net

While serializing a Flags long Enum, protobuf-net throws a System.Overflow exception. Here's a schematic description of what I'm doing:

**Class being serialized:**

```
[ProtoContract()]
public class Entry
{
   [ProtoMember(1)]
   public FancyLongEnum FancyLongEnum {get;set;}
}
```

**The Enum:**

```
[ProtoContract(ImplicitFields = ImplicitFields.AllFields, EnumPassthru = true)]
[Flags]
public enum FancyLongEnum : long
{
    FirstFancyValue = 1,
    [...]
    LastFancyValue = 137438953472
}
```

**The result:**

```
System.OverflowException: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.
```

A workaround is to use a wrapper long property and ignore the FancyLongEnum during serialization. However, I was hoping there is a cleaner way.

A similar issue was discussed in [Error while using ProtoBuf-Net with flags enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494939/error-while-using-protobuf-net-with-flags-enum). It resulted in a fix to protobuf-net.

How can I make serialization work directly, without resorting to wrapper property?

Comment: That appears to be a bug, plain and simple. I have logged this for you: https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net/issues/142. The workaround is the dummy property; the fix will need library changes.

Comment: Thanks for confirming it @MarcGravell! (and for the quick response too) I'll stick with the dummy property for now. Other than that, thank you for this damn fast serialization library!